# Python TCP sockets won't connect

Tags: python, sockets

As part of a uni course, I have to write a simple python TCP client-server chat but I'm having issues getting the sockets in the server.py and client.py programs to connect.

After many attempts I decided to really strip back the program to just try to connect the sockets and have the client send one message to the server after they are connected.

I am running the two programs (server.py and client.py) on the same computer (macOS) in separate terminal windows. I have tried turning off the firewall and running the programs as well just in case that was somehow causing an issue.

My code is as below:

server.py - This is run first

```
from socket import *
serverPort = 11500
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))

print("The server is listening")
serverSocket.listen(1)

clientSocket, clientAddress = serverSocket.accept()

message, clientAddress = serverSocket.recvfrom(2048)
```

client.py - Once server.py is running, this is then started

```
from socket import *

serverName = "127.0.0.1"
serverPort = 11500

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort))

message = "Hello"
clientSocket.send(message.encode())
```

This is the error I have been receiving:

```
(base) me@ME python_socket % python3 tcp_server.py
The server is listening
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tcp_server.py", line 11, in <module>
    message, clientAddress = serverSocket.recvfrom(2048)
OSError: [Errno 57] Socket is not connected
```

Thanks in advance for any help. It seems like something that should be really simple but even after watching tutorials online I still seem to have the issue of the sockets not connecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problems

1. You should use `recv()` instead of `recvfrom()` when you connect using TCP. `recvfrom()` is used for UDP socket.
2. Instead of receiving data from `serverSocket`, you should use newly created TCP `clientSocket`.

### Correct Solution

#### Server

```py
from socket import *

serverPort = 11500
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(("localhost", serverPort))

print("The server is listening")
serverSocket.listen(1)

clientSocket, clientAddress = serverSocket.accept()
message = clientSocket.recv(2048).decode()
print(message)
```

#### Client

```py
from socket import *

serverName = "127.0.0.1"
serverPort = 11500

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort))

message = "Hello"
clientSocket.send(message.encode())
```

##### Server Output:

```py
The server is listening
Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that, in the `server.py` code, you should replace `serverSocket` in the `recvfrom` line with `clientSocket`, since when you call `accept` right before that line, `clientSocket` (returned by `accept`)  is a new socket specific to that connection.

```
clientSocket, clientAddress = serverSocket.accept()

message, clientAddress = clientSocket.recvfrom(2048)
```

After that change, it is going to work just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I saw in another answer that as well as not using the correct socket, I should be using recv() instead of recvfrom() as I am dealing with TCP and not UDP.